# Adding color to points in Multi-Line D3 Graph; re-render on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm currently working on creating a multi-line graph. My working code can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/1uszmp73/3/

I'm having two issues. one is minor, the other will take some explanation.

**Minor Issue:**
I cannot get the point color to match the line color. You will see that line commented out on Line # 117. What am I doing wrong? Is it in how I am defining my circle placement itself?

```
    //style the circles set their location based on data
var circles = metrics.selectAll("dot")
        .data(function(d) {return d.Data;})
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circles")
      .attr("r", 4)
      /*.style("fill", function (d) {return color(d.Metric);}) -- this is where I'm having issues */ 
      .attr("cx", function (d) {return xScale(parseDate(d.Date)); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {return yScale(d.Value)});
```

**Major Issue:**
I'd love some suggestions on how to toggle between showing data for "Model A" and "Model B" and how to redraw the graph on change. I've tried to look up some solutions, but I keep erroring out, or nothing is picked up. Either way, I don't have any consistent or repeatable errors to give, so I just back-tracked to code I knew was working.

I'd love to implement something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/17aa30fd98eb0cc7072f) but I'm not sure how to apply those solutions with my specific nested data set. Additionally, I have a service in place that will filter the data FOR me, so ideally on dropdown change I would only  return a data set like this:

```
{
"Model": "Model A", 
"Data": [
    {
        "Metric": "Metric 1", 
        "Data": [
                {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "34"}, 
                {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "52"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "47"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "50"}
         ]
    }, 
    {
        "Metric": "Metric 2", 
        "Data": [
                {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "22"}, 
                {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "27"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "25"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "21"}
         ]
    }, 
    {
        "Metric": "Metric 3", 
        "Data": [
                {"Date":"2017-2-25", "Value": "27"}, 
                {"Date":"2017-2-26", "Value": "28"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-27", "Value": "25"},
                {"Date":"2017-2-28", "Value": "22"}
         ]
    }
]
```

}

I just can't seem to hook it up so on dropdown the graph will re-render with the new source.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated you [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojpaxtth/2/) to get the matching colors. Basically, the dot are bound to the sub-arrays, so the property of the parent has to be retrieved:

```
var circles = metrics.selectAll("dot")
    .data(function(d) {return d.Data;})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circles")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .style("fill", function (d) {return color(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().Metric);}) //current data is the sub-array. To match the color, the data from the parent must be used.
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return xScale(parseDate(d.Date)); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {return yScale(d.Value)});
```

As for you update idea, you would need to apply the enter-update-delete pattern. The bl.ocks you posted seems to highlight it pretty well, in particular:

```
var state = svg.selectAll(".line")
  .data(result, function(d){return d.key});

    state.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "line");

    state.transition()
        .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key); })
        .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');}) // assign ID
        .attr("d", function(d){

            return stateline(d.values)
        });

    state.exit().remove();
```

The basic idea is:

- bind to the data
- create new elements as needed
- update relevent properties
- remove useless elements

Your code looks nicely structured so that should not be too hard. Try to split the part that are specific to new elements from the one that apply to both existing and new ones.

On a side note, I would recommend using d3 v4 to look to the future :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response -- very clear! 

I found this walkthrough as well, which was pretty simplistic, but also another good explanation.  

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html